# In dask_jobqueue, how to add extra lines to job_script?

Tags: dask

I'm configuring dask to run on an HPC cluster. I setup a client as follows:

First modify `~/.config/dask/*.yaml` then run some code like this:

```
from dask_jobqueue import SLURMCluster

cluster = SLURMCluster()
cluster.scale(100)          # Start 100 workers in 100 jobs

from distributed import Client
client = Client(cluster)
print(cluster.job_script())
```

Here's what the resultant job_script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH -J dask-worker
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=1GB
#SBATCH -t 00:30:00
JOB_ID=${SLURM_JOB_ID%;*}

/path/to/python3 -m distributed.cli.dask_worker tcp://192.168.*.*:* --nthreads 1 --memory-limit 1000.00MB --name dask-worker--${JOB_ID}-- --death-timeout 60 --local-directory /scratch
```

So the script launches python3 immediately, but I need to make it do some stuff like activating a conda environment, or python virtual env before launching python. How can I add some pre-commands to the job_script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, by reading source code of `dask_jobqueue/core.py`, which was thankfully very easy.

In `~/.config/dask/jobqueue.yaml`, edit `env-extra`. Each string in the list is added to the script as a command. For example, when using

```
env-extra: ['cd foo', 'mkdir bar', 'cd bar', 'conda foo']
```

The job_script comes out like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#!/usr/bin/env bash
#SBATCH -J dask-worker
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --mem=1GB
#SBATCH -t 00:30:00
JOB_ID=${SLURM_JOB_ID%;*}

cd foo
mkdir bar
cd bar
conda foo

/path/to/python3 -m distributed.cli.dask_worker tcp://192.168.*.*:* --nthreads 1 --memory-limit 1000.00MB --name dask-worker--${JOB_ID}-- --death-timeout 60 --local-directory /scratch
```